# locus of a complex number in the form |z-a|=k|z-b|

Tags: complex-numbers

how does one find the locus of a set of complex numbers defined in the form |z-a|=k|z-b|

for example in the question (CIE ALEVELS MATHS/9709/May-June 2013/Paper 33/Question 7) below we have to find the locus of the set of complex numbers |z-10i|=2|z-4i|

i looked through the internet and got to know that such equation is not represented by an angular bisector in the argan diagram as i previous thought but by a circle

an answer with respect to the question would be really appreciated (especially part iii)

[image: the question]

Answer (score 2):

Distance from a point is $k$ times the distance from another point where $k\neq1,>0$, the locus is a circle. It is called Apollonius circle.

You can prove it simply putting $z=x+i y$ and squaring both sides. You can find the centre and radius by locating $2$ points of circle on the line joining both points using section formula.  These two will be diametrically opposite points.

Comment: so what will be the center of the circle and how much will the radius be equal to?

Comment: @phantom.omaga edited.

Comment: O.o section formula? sorry i am not getting it even after your explanation. Can you please explain it with reference to the question above or any other dummy values perhaps then it might go through my thick head :) sorry again.

Comment: Can you find centre and radius of circle by using its equation? It is an alternate method.

Comment: and how is that done?

Comment: @phantom.omaga Google.

Comment: FYI Google and Wikipedia no help so far.

Comment: @phantom.omaga Write equation as $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$ where (h,k) is centre and $r$ is radius. Expand this and compare with equation you got while putting z=x+iy . you will find h,k,r.